# Density results

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a Reflexive Banach space $V$ that is compactly embedded into a Hilbert sapce $H$, which is continuously embedded into a Banach space $W:= V'$ (with $W$ being the dual of $V$, that is $V'$) and with $H$ being identified with its dual.

How can I prove that $V$ is dense in $H$? Is it possible for Sobolev spaces? I mean, take $H = L^2$ and $V = W_{0}^{1, p}$; so $W = (W_{0}^{1, p})' = W^{-1, p'}$. How can I have density in $L^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $V\subset\subset H$, i.e., compact embedding, we have the identity mapping $I$: $V\to H$ is an compact operator. Then, $I': H=H'\to V'$ is the adjoint operator of $I$ from $H'\to V'$. Then by the properties of adjoint operator, we know that $I'$ is compact as well, and this is the best result you can have.